# Contar quantidade de registros únicos em um Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho uma base com uma coluna `custumer_id` e preciso saber a quantidade de registros únicos na base.

```
quantidade_clientes = df[['customer_id']]
quantidade_clientes.count()
```

Desse jeito eu conto todo mundo, quero saber só quem é único.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O pandas possui a função `.nunique()`, que retorna a quantidade de valores únicos em um [Data Frame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) ou uma [Série](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html). No seu caso, basta fazer:

```
df['customer_id'].nunique()
```